# How to block AWS Lamba testing through AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, aws-lambda

I have a AWS Lambda function in production. Triggering it can lead to monetary transactions. I want to block the feature of testing this lambda through AWS console so that users having console access cannot accidentally trigger it for the purpose of testing which they can do on the corresponding staging lambda. Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 5):

First solution that I would recommend is to not mix production and other workloads in the same AWS account. Combine that with not giving your developers and users credentials to the production account.

Assuming that you don't want to do that, you could apply a [resource policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html) on the Lambda function that denies all regular IAM users permission to invoke the Lambda function. Be sure that your policy does not deny the 'real' source in your production system (e.g. API Gateway or SQS or S3). You should also prevent your users from modifying the resource policy on the Lambda function.

Alternatively, if all of your IAM users are managed under IAM groups, then you could apply an additional group policy that denied all actions on the Lambda function ARN. Again, ensure that they cannot modify the group policy to remove this control.